# Comparação de caracteres de strings em C

Tags: c, string

Estou tentando fazer um exercício que testa se existe algum espaço em branco antes de uma *string* e remove se tiver, porém está retornando o seguinte erro:

> Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)

Não consigo entender o motivo.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void removerEspacosEsquerda(char string[]) {
    int i, j, cont;
    char *string2, a;
    i = 0;
    cont = 0;
    while(string[i] != 0) {
        if(string[i] == ' ') {
            cont++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    printf("%d", cont);
    while(string[i] != 0) {
        if(i >= cont) {
            string2[j] = string[i];
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    string = string2;
}
int main() {
    char *string;
    string = " teste";
    removerEspacosEsquerda(string);
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Seu código é complexo demais e o erro ocorreu por causa disto, quando simplificamos ele o erro nem tem oportunidade de aparecer. Não precisa ter 2 *loops* (3 pela solução da outra resposta) e não precisa ter alocação de memória:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removerEspacosEsquerda(char string[]) {
    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++, cont++) {
        if (string[i] == ' ') cont--;
        else string[cont] = string[i];
    }
    string[cont] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char string[] = " teste";
    removerEspacosEsquerda(string);
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iVYzjm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ijghnovm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/RemoveLeftSpaces.c).

Answer (score 1):

A falha de segmentação ocorre porque o ponteiro "string2" não foi inicializado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // para malloc e free

void removerEspacosEsquerda(char string[])
{
  int i, j, cont;
  char *string2 = malloc(strlen(string)+1), a; // <-------------
  i = 0;
  ....
  ....
  strcpy(string, string2);
  free(string2); // <-------------
} // fim removerEspacosEsquerda
```

Note que não analisei se sua lógica de remoção de espaços está correta, estou apenas resolvendo o problema da falha de segmentação.